# jQuery: Exclude those td, having child element Label with class "control-label"

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select all td in document using jQuery,excluding those td which have child element label with class name "control-label".

```
<td width="30%"><label class="control-label">IP Address</label></td>
```

I tried:

```
jQuery("table td").not("table td > label.control-label").attr('width','');
```

Comment: Do you have a typo - `lable.control-label` instead of `label.control-label` ?

Comment: @Robin thanks for point it out, but it's not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this selection:

```
$('td:not(:has(> .control-label))');
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
jQuery('table td:not(:has( > .control-label[width]))')
```

Comment: Sorry, but too early i voted it. actually not working as i wanted. it's leaving all td[width] as it is.

Comment: it should work with `jQuery("table td:not(.control-label[width]");`

Comment: the .control-label is a class of child element <label> of td

Comment: so try this `jQuery("table td:not(td > .control-label[width]");`

Comment: i don't know what `[width]` will do but not working for me. i tried `jQuery("table td:not(td > .control-label[width]").attr('width','');` basically i am trying to remove the width. but no worries the above answer from @Martin works.

Comment: `jQuery('table td:not(:has( > .control-label[width]))');`
This should work!

Answer (score 0):

I think following code help you.

```
$('td label:not(.control-label)');
```